# Jquery regex replace with search

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to replace a string `text9 text text` to `9` only.

The code below is working but returning literally `{1}`

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/text([0-9]+)[ \t]text text/g,'{1}'));
```

Instead of returning literally `{1}`, I want it to return the `[0-9]+` from the search.

How would you do that with Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code

```
yourstring.replace(/text([0-9]+)[ \t]text text/g, '{1}');
```

with this:

```
yourstring.replace(/text([0-9]+)[ \t]text text/g, '$1');
```

and your code will be like:

```
$('body').html(function (_, html) {
    return html.replace(/text([0-9]+)[ \t]text text/g, '$1');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UmJ5M/)